# Select a node in the DOM with xpath/3

Tags: xpath, prolog

I have a problem to extract a specific element in DOM.
For example i use this code:

```
   xpath(DOM, //table(1), TABLE)
```

and i have access to the first table. But if i try to access to the second table i use this code:

```
   xpath(DOM, //table(2), TABLE)
```

but it fail and i haven't the second table.

Is it possible to select a specific node in the DOM with xpath/3?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're reusing the same variable, and that can't work:

```
:- [library(xpath)].

table(N, T) :-
    DOM = element(xx, [],
          [  element(table, [], [a,b,c]),
             element(table, [], [x,y,z])
          ]),
    xpath(DOM, //table(N), T).
```

with that fragment, as expected

```
?- table(2,T).
T = element(table, [], [x, y, z])
```

but

```
?- table(1,T), table(2,T).
false.
```

Comment: Just to clarify, it can't work because `element(table, [], [a,b,c])` can't unify with `element(table, [], [x,y,z])`. If you wanted only to match cases where you had the same table in the input document twice it would be meaningful. That probably never happens in practice though.

Answer (score 0):

Selection (or predicates) in xpath are embedded in []-brackets.
For example

```
//table[1]
//table[2]
//table[last()-1]
//table[@someattribute='somevalue']
```

etc.

---

EDIT: It seems I missed the prolog-tag. In prolog it seems that xpath predicates are not specified by square brackets but by parenthesis: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=xpath%2F3 . But according to that documentation your code sample should work as intended.